# Flutter: How to use child original constraints in SingleChildLayoutDelegate

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making use of `CustomSingleChildLayout` to create a custom popup. The popup widget will be in the overlay. The `getConstraintsForChild` method returns the biggest constraints possible whereas I want it to return the child's original constraints.

### Details

This is the method that I am using to create the `OverlayEntry`

```
void createOverlayEntry() {
  RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;

  entry = OverlayEntry(
    builder: (context) {
      return CustomSingleChildLayout(
        delegate: _PopupContentDelegate(
          parentSize: renderBox.size,
          parentOffset: renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero),
          offset: offset,
        ),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );

  Overlay.of(context).insert(entry);
}
```

With the implementation below, I am getting the full size of the `Overlay` and the child takes all the available space.

```
class _PopupContentDelegate extends SingleChildLayoutDelegate {
  final Size parentSize;
  final Offset parentOffset;
  final Offset offset;

  _PopupContentDelegate({
    required this.parentSize,
    required this.parentOffset,
    required this.offset,
  });

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(covariant SingleChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return this != oldDelegate;
  }

  @override
  BoxConstraints getConstraintsForChild(BoxConstraints constraints) {
    // Should return the original constraints of the child
    return super.getConstraintsForChild(constraints);
  }

  @override
  Offset getPositionForChild(Size size, Size childSize) {
    double dx = 0, dy = 0;

    // Find the ideal vertical position.
    dy = -childSize.height - offset.dy;

    // Find the ideal horizontal position.
    dx = (parentSize.width - childSize.width) / 2 + offset.dx;

    // ...some other calculations

    return parentOffset.translate(dx, dy);
  }
}
```

If I pass in a `Size` parameter to the `_PopupContentDelegate` class I would be to use it to construct the child's constraints. However, this doesn't work well when I don't know the child's size beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class _PopupContentDelegate extends SingleChildLayoutDelegate {
  final Size parentSize;
  final Offset parentOffset;
  final Offset offset;

  _PopupContentDelegate({
    required this.parentSize,
    required this.parentOffset,
    required this.offset,
  });

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(covariant SingleChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return this != oldDelegate;
  }

  @override
  BoxConstraints getConstraintsForChild(BoxConstraints constraints) {
   
    return BoxConstraints(
      minWidth: 0.0,
      maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
      minHeight: 0.0,
      maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
    );
  }

  @override
  Offset getPositionForChild(Size size, Size childSize) {
    double dx = 0, dy = 0;

    dy = -childSize.height - offset.dy;

    dx = (parentSize.width - childSize.width) / 2 + offset.dx;

    return parentOffset.translate(dx, dy);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's still giving me the same result. However, when I set `minWidth` and `minHeight` to `0.0` it works as expected now